# Can PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE replace PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm dealing with `PendingIntent` with `notification`.
In my project, I've been using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in some of code. and the definition of it is below.

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists,
> then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new
> Intent. For use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int),
> getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int,
> Intent, int).
>
> This can be used if you are creating intents where only the extras
> change, and don't care that any entities that received your previous
> PendingIntent will be able to launch it with your new extras even if
> they are not explicitly given to it.
>
> FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT still works even if FLAG_IMMUTABLE is set - the
> creator of the PendingIntent can always update the PendingIntent
> itself. The IMMUTABLE flag only limits the ability to alter the
> semantics of the intent that is sent by send() by the invoker of
> send().

But I have to choose between `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` or `FLAG_MUTABLE` because of Android12. In my case, i don't need to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE`. the definition of it is below.

> Flag indicating that the created PendingIntent should be immutable.
> This means that the additional intent argument passed to the send
> methods to fill in unpopulated properties of this intent will be
> ignored.
>
> FLAG_IMMUTABLE only limits the ability to alter the semantics of the
> intent that is sent by send() by the invoker of send(). The creator of
> the PendingIntent can always update the PendingIntent itself via
> FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT.

as you can see, they say "FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT still works even if FLAG_IMMUTABLE is set..." and "The creator of the PendingIntent can always update the PendingIntent itself via FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT."

So, what i want to know is that `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` can perfectly replace `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in any Android version?

**For example**

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
=> PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

Comment: They're flags; they aren't mutually exclusive. Why aren't you just using both? Or is your question _how_ to use both?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I heared that if i use `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` , then there is no need to use 'FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` together. that's why i'm confusing now and asked this question. since the document says it seemd to be used together as you said. So, i'll ask you again, What I want is that it works the same as when I used 'FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT' and I want to satisfy 'FLAG_IMMUTABLE' because of Android12. and you're right. they're flags. then, should i just use array of flags like this?
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent, int[FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENt, FLAG_IMMUTABLE]); ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FLAG_IMMUTABLE` and `FLAT_MUTABLE` controls if **other apps** can modify your `PendingIntent`. For instance, if you were using a [direct reply action](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#reply-action) in a notification, the system would need you to use `FLAT_MUTABLE` to allow it to fill in the text the user typed and send it to you.

`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is the ability for **your app** to update its own `PendingIntent`. This means if you create the same `PendingIntent` where the only difference is the extras attached to your `Intent`, `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` would ensure that your new extras are actually used (instead of just the original set being used again).

So in every case where you were using `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, you'd want to **continue** to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, adding in the correct mutability flag for your case (which, in 99% of cases, is `FLAG_IMMUTABLE`).

To apply both flags, use the `|` symbol in Java (or the word `or` in Kotlin):

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```